# dropdownlist problem with the use of ajax and php

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

I have some problem with on of the pages of a project.
I have 1 drop down on top of the page , and in that list the items are - today , last week.
Now according to that list item-value , below that drop down list  records should be displayed from the database.

dummy code:

```
if today
then
records with current date should be displayed 

and if last week
then
records with date in last week should be displayed
```

Comment: What is your question exactly? Where are you stuck?

Comment: how to display records from database according to items in one drop down list???  in short , if 'today' is selected from drop down list then records from database with today's date should be displayed in table manner

Answer (score 0):

First drop-down on which 2nd drop-down will be shown -

```
<select name="day" onchange="itemsToShowFor();">
<option value="today">Today</option>
<option value="last_week">Last Week</option>
</select>
```

Container of Table - Records

```
<div id="records"></div>
```

Script for update Table of Records -

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){    
    itemsToShowFor();
});

function itemsToShowFor(){
  var itemToShowFor = $("select:[name=day]").val();
  $.ajax({
      type:'POST',
      url:URL_TO_GET_ITEMS,
      data:[day:itemToShowFor ],
      success:function(list){
          $("#records").html(list); // list will contain records formatted with HTML 
      }
      });
}

</script>
```

Comment: i dnt wnt records as items of other drop down list after selecting one drop down list. i just want records as a table form. pls tel me for this .. i dnt know much php